# Mysql Multiple Unique Keys

Tags: mysql, on-duplicate-key

Is it possible to have an or option when multiple unique keys?

For example i what to to check on this key or this key and if one kick out a duplicate error then update on that key?

I have 2 unique keys: UPN and (username,school)

We use a on duplicate update statement in out MYSQL. if UPN is passed then update on upn key if  duplicate or insert new row. i want to to check on UPN and (username,school) and do the following:

If upn match update on that
If (username,school) match update on that
if upn dosnt match but (username,school) do update on (username,school) match
If upn match and (username,school) dosnt update on UPN match

So i need it to use or instead of and, is this possible?

Ash

Answer (score 1):

You can emulate this with conditional operators in the `ON DUPLICATE` clause of the query:

```
INSERT INTO thetable (id, username, school, othervalue)
VALUES (10, 'newtover', 'cool school', 'a comment')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  username = IF(id = VALUES(id), VALUES(username), username),
  school = IF(id = VALUES(id), VALUES(school), school),
  id = IF(id = VALUES(id), id, VALUES(id));
```

The order of updates in this case is significant.